# Flutter - Generic json serializer with Dart

Tags: json, flutter, generics, dart

I'm new in Flutter and trying to implement something similar to Swift generic decodable, like below:

```
struct ParentJson<T>: Decodable where T: Decodable
```

After hours of searching, I found out there are 2 libraries serving same purpose [built_value](https://pub.dev/packages/built_value) and [json_annotation](https://github.com/dart-lang/json_serializable) and a sentence says, 
**[Dart does not do generic type erasure](https://github.com/google/built_value.dart/issues/592#issuecomment-550207626)**.

---

I'm trying to parse json below:

```
{ 
    "status": 200,
    "message": "This message", 
    "data": { 
        "uid": "tested",
        "email": "test@gmail.com",
        "name": "test"
    } 
}
```

In this case `data` can be different and this is the place I want to make data generic.

---

With [built_value generic example](https://github.com/cnzhuzi/Flutter-Json-Generic-with-built_value-Sample) `T` have to be specified as specifiedType in `addBuilderFactory` as David mentioned [here](https://github.com/google/built_value.dart/issues/592#issuecomment-550207626).

And [this](https://github.com/dart-lang/json_serializable/commit/ee2c5c788279af01860624303abe16811850b82c) is an official example with json_annotation.

Both ways totally violates the concepts of generic, since I need to declare all different types in parent classes or serializers, instead of simply write a code like this:

```
Parent<User> user = Parent<User>.deserialize(json.decode(jsonString))
```

**So my question from Dart and Flutter experts is,**

- Is this a Dart language limitation?
- Is there any way to implement generic value for parsing json without
  violating generic concept?

Comment: Dart generics are reified so I don't imagine it's a language limitation.

Comment: @AluanHaddad, well this 2 libraries are recommended by Andrew and Matt from Flutter team and its handling multiple object states, which is really important to avoid memory leak in Flutter, but unfortunately I couldn't find any example online to parse json with generic object.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any experience using Flutter, I was just remarking that it should be possible do to the reification generic types.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is a solution for your use case. 
It's a https://github.com/k-paxian/dart-json-mapper library.

I'm pretty sure you are looking for something like [this](https://github.com/k-paxian/dart-json-mapper/blob/master/mapper/test/test.generics.dart). 
You'll find working unit tests illustrating your use case.